# Python OS X Macports: Hangs when installing scipy

Tags: python, scipy, llvm, osx-mavericks

When attempting to install py27-scipy on OS X 10.9, it hangs at:

```
--->  Attempting to fetch llvm-3.3-3.3_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/llvm-3.3
```

Specifically, I used `sudo port install py27-scipy`

I can install other py27 ports this way (e.g. py27-numpy) and I can install llvm-3.3 independently, yet when I attempt to install py27-scipy it just hangs here. The last 30 lines of the log are:

```
:debug:main Finished running callback portbuild::add_automatic_buildsystem_dependencies
:debug:main No need to upgrade! libffi 3.0.13_0 >= libffi 3.0.13_0
:debug:main epoch: in tree: 0 installed: 0
:debug:main perl5 5.12.4_0 exists in the ports tree
:debug:main perl5 5.12.4_0 +perl5_12 is the latest installed
:debug:main perl5 5.12.4_0 +perl5_12 is active
:debug:main Merging existing variants '+perl5_12' into variants
:debug:main new fully merged portvariants: perl5_12 +
:debug:main Changing to port directory: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/lang/perl5
:debug:main OS darwin/13.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9) arch i386
:debug:main universal_variant is false, so not adding the default universal variant
:debug:main Executing variant perl5_12 provides perl5_12
:debug:main Running callback portconfigure::add_automatic_compiler_dependencies
:debug:main Finished running callback portconfigure::add_automatic_compiler_dependencies
:debug:main Running callback portbuild::add_automatic_buildsystem_dependencies
:debug:main Finished running callback portbuild::add_automatic_buildsystem_dependencies
:debug:main No need to upgrade! perl5 5.12.4_0 >= perl5 5.12.4_0
:debug:main epoch: in tree: 0 installed: 0
:debug:main perl5.12 5.12.4_3 exists in the ports tree
:debug:main perl5.12 5.12.4_3  is the latest installed
:debug:main perl5.12 5.12.4_3  is active
:debug:main Merging existing variants '' into variants
:debug:main new fully merged portvariants:
:debug:main Changing to port directory: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/lang/perl5.12
:debug:main OS darwin/13.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9) arch i386
:debug:main adding the default universal variant
:debug:main Reading variant descriptions from /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/_resources/port1.0/variant_descriptions.conf
:debug:main Running callback portconfigure::add_automatic_compiler_dependencies
:debug:main Finished running callback portconfigure::add_automatic_compiler_dependencies
:debug:main Running callback portbuild::add_automatic_buildsystem_
```

(EOF)

Not sure where to look from here. Anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: This is happening to me too. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Heh, an hour later and it is finished. Perhaps the file is very large.

Comment: I never solved this exact problem; I think I waited for hours but I can't remember. I just installed Anaconda, which ships with SciPy, and that was good enough for me.